# How to determine the units used in odom_combined and Twist on Turtlebot Kobuki?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, kobuki, odom-combined

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to figure out how the measurements received from the rostopic,  odom_combined
(geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped) relate to real world units. For example, when I input the following command: `rostopic echo odom_combined`. I received the following output

```
pose:
   pose:
       position:
           x: -0.9762
           y: -2.1532
           z: 0.0
       orientation:
           x: 0.0
           y: 0.0
           z: -0.6230
           w: 0.7821
```

I think that orientation is in radians, but I cannot figure out the units of position. I moved the turtlebot from x: -0.9762 to x: 0.9762, but, when I measured the actual distanced moved, I got 12 feet 7 inches.

I am also trying to figure out the units of twist. I think that orientation in twist is in radians per second, but I do not know what units position is in.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60176/how-to-determine-the-units-used-in-odom_combined-and-twist-on-turtlebot-kobuki?/) by [James 412](https://answers.ros.org/users/2989/james-412/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most units used inside ROS are SI units (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units). Although you can't rely on it, that's usually a good assumption. Have a look at the message descriptions. Sometimes you find useful information there.

So, in your case position/translation is measured in meters and rotation in radians. If you see a rotation description with x, y, z, w, than that's a quaternion.

If your measurement data (e.g. odom) doesn't align with your real world measurements, than your software and/or hardware introduces these errors. For example, the Create's/TurtleBot 1's odometry is very unreliable.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4